# nservicebus unsubscribing when we want it to subscribe

Tags: nservicebus

We have an NServiceBus 3.0 publisher running under the production profile.

When a subscriber starts up it sends the subscription messages to the publisher but the publisher does not add them to Raven. Infact in the publisher's log is the entry:

```
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Unsubscribing subscriber@servername from message type MyMessage, MyMessages, Version=1.0.20323.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXX
```

When the bus does a Publish() the subscriber does not receive a message because it would seem as if the publisher cannot process the subscriptions.

Any help would be stellar as we have a demo tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that all your endpoints are 3.0.1. 300 is not compatible with 301 without the nsb.compatibility.dll in the bin dir

Comment: Thanks Andreas you were right - there was a version mismatch. The publisher was still using the rc-5 libraries and the subscriber was using 301. Very confusing!

Comment: Andreas, does this mean if you want to use 3.3 publishers with 4.X subscribers you need to use unobtrusive mode messages?